# Displaying questions in a quiz application in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

I am currently trying to make a quiz generator application in JavaFX using Scenebuilder to design the GUI. 
The user specifies a number and the application displays that many number of randomly chosen questions (MCQ, True or False, or Fill in the blank) from a database. 
How would you display this list of questions in the GUI given that the number of questions can vary and the types of the individual questions can also vary?

Comment: Something with a scrollbar?

Comment: You can use a `ListView` with a custom `CellRenderer` that build UI for every question based on its type.

Comment: @RafaelGuillen seems like just the thing I wanted. I am pretty new to programming and was afraid my question wasn't too clear

Comment: Check this Github repo: https://github.com/lestard/todomvcFX, is the same application that uses ListViews built with JavaFX with different patterns and frameworks.